# Toponogov comparison theorem for complex manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I would like to know some reference for the Toponogov comparison theorem for complex manifolds, in particular for complex manifolds with bounded holomorphic sectional curvature. As far as I know, the Toponogov comparison theorem for manifolds with bounded Ricci curvature tensor has been proved by Guofang Wei.